# Clone TFS 2017 to new hardware

Tags: tfs

We have TFS 2017.2 in 'Prod' and now I have to clone it on new PC to take some tests and so on.

I did DB backups with the help of TFS Scheduled Backup tool (Configuration DB, Collection, Warehouse, ReportServer, and ReportSerfer_tempDB), installed TFS 2017.2 on new PC, restore DBs.

After it I start `TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:spbtfs01fortest /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration' and 'TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName:spbtfs01fortest;TFS_Configuration /SQLInstances:spbtfs01fortest` and start the Server Configuration Wizard, filled in all and got this:

[image]

What wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run [`tfsconfig remapdbs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs) for the analysis services database (with `/AnalysisInstance`), and for the warehouse database as well for the collection and configuration databases.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have SQL with installed SQL Server Analysis Services (Running - Automatic), but I don't see any DB to be specified. On my 'Prod' I don't have any SQL Analysis DBs too. tfsconfig remapdbs demand to point Analysis DB but I have no ideas where is it?

Comment: Do I have any methods to find on 'Prod' TFS where is Tfs_Analysis DB?

Comment: You may find that on TFS Administration Console section Reporting [Add Reporting to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/add-a-report-server?view=tfs-2018#add-reporting-to-tfs)

Comment: Has anyone cloned TFS 2017.2 with Reporting Service from one server to another? What are the steps to do it correctly?